# Triple selection in Chrome result in multiple line selection

Tags: ckeditor, range, selection

I'm implementing a WYSIWYG on top of CKEditor4 ( basically I'm just rewriting the toolbar ). 
The problem is that dragging the mouse to select and triple-clicking a line to select it, produces different ranges.

With this html:

```
<h2>^Leo ac scegliere e iniziare^</h2> <<< Line I want to select
<p>nunc ultrices eros, sed gravida</p>
```

These are the ranges produced in different scenarios:

**right-to-left** and **left-to-right**

`startContainer` and `endContainer` are the same, it reflects the actual situation from the user point of view.

```
collapsed: false
document:CKEDITOR.dom.document {$: document}
endContainer: CKEDITOR.dom.element {$: h2, getName: ƒ}
endOffset: 1 
startContainer: CKEDITOR.dom.element {$: h2, getName: ƒ}
startOffset: 0
```

**triple-selection**

`startContainer` and `endContainer` are not the same, it doesn't reflect the actual situation from the user point of view.

```
collapsed: false
document:CKEDITOR.dom.document {$: document}
endContainer: CKEDITOR.dom.element {$: p, getName: ƒ}
endOffset: 0 
startContainer: CKEDITOR.dom.element {$: h2, getName: ƒ}
startOffset: 0
```

This difference is causing me problems in style applying.
This is happening in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Any idea of why is this happening? Any solution? I've been thinking about a solution that checks the `endContainer` and `endOffset` but I'm afraid that such solution can break range and selection providing unexpected behaviors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As result of a `mouseup` `event` I came up with this:

```
fuction handleMouseup(event) {
  if (event.detail === 3) {
    const selection = this.editor.getSelection()
    let range = selection.getRanges()[0]
    let actualStartContainer = range.startContainer

    // Finds the highest parent untill the startContainer
    while (!actualStartContainer.getParent().equals(this.editor.element))
        actualStartContainer = actualStartContainer.getParent()

    // Select the ranges and update the selection with just the startContainer
    range.selectNodeContents(actualStartContainer)
    selection.selectRanges([range])
  }
}
```